# What are the terms to use when talking about things you want to sell to other people?

Tags: synonyms

I'm searching for a term used when talking about things you want to sell to other people. Any synonyms for them would be appreciated to.

I mean the items, products, or other stuff you want to sell

Comment: Forgot to add: I mean the items, products or other stuff you want to sell

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ware) has the example *traders in the street markets displayed their **wares*** (articles offered for sale).

Comment: What properties does this term need to have? Why aren't _items_ or _products_ suitable terms?

Comment: I think some salespeople refer to those items as their "line".

Comment: We need a *lot* more detail about the intended context. For example, I'm not a retailer, so I wouldn't talk about my ***wares***. But I might look for some some ***monetizable assets*** in my loft, cellar, and garage. And if I was a musician going out on tour, I'd probably want to take plenty of ***merch*** with me to sell at my gigs.

Comment: Please provide much-needed detail...are you a kid selling stuff you found in the garage, or are you a proprietor of an outlet?

Comment: “Come inside and take a look at the **goods**.”

Comment: So the assumption is that these are goods rather than services? What’s wrong with goods?

Answer (score 1):

***line***

> 11 : merchandise or services of the same general class for sale or regularly available

ex. *a full **line** of electrical supplies*

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line)

When I was a kid, I used to work at a local HoJo's as a bellhop and I often heard traveling salesmen use the word when introducing themselves to others of the same ilk.

e.g.

> "What's your line?"

Comment: This is a business term, not a term for a kid selling his personal belongings and suchlike,

Comment: Why do you think this is a "kid selling his personal belongings etc"?

Answer (score 0):

**Truck** could be the word you're looking for

> Articles of commerce; trade goods

[American Heritage Dictionary]